# Conditional prevention of the textbox change

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, event-handling

I have a TextBox, and a TextBlock within the Border. The TextBlock's Text property is bound to TextBox's value. When I type into the TextBox, the Border changes its width according to the TextBlock's new size.

There is an event handler for TextBox.TextChanged in which I test whether the size of the border exceeds a certain number. If it does, I want to prevent the TextBox from making the change that caused the handler.

If a character was always added to an end, I would be able just to substring the text, but all other sorts of changing can occur, for example pasting a large amount of text into the TextBox.

So, what would be the way of preventing the change from the handler? I remember in some WindowsForms e.Cancel property which when set would ignore the action, but haven't seen that in WPF and the TextChangedEventArgs obviously does not have one.

Thanks

Comment: [Dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335129/cancelling-a-wpf-textbox-changed-event).

Comment: if this is still an issue, please add the of your TextBox.TextChanged event handler. Else please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `PreviewTextInput` event and set `e.Handled` to true to prevent the change from taking effect.