# wpf attribute instead of e.keychar in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I created a textbox dynamically with a TextChangedEventArgs to restrict the textbox to enter only numbers and decimal point.
Following is the code in c#

```
const char Delete = (char)8;
if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
else if (e.KeyChar == Delete)
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
else if (e.KeyChar == '.')
{
    if (!(amt.Text.Contains(".")))
        e.Handled = false;
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
else
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

But I can't use this in wpf.

I tried to change the code with e.key or e.Text. But both these are not available. It is showing the following error Are u missing an assembly or directive.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Again, you should learn MVVM and stop trying to create the entire UI in procedural code. That's what XAML is for. WPF and all other XAML-based frameworks are fundamentally different from ancient traditional frameworks and require a different mindset to work with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancelling a WPF TextBox Changed Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335129/cancelling-a-wpf-textbox-changed-event)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    // one solution for filtering characters in a textbox.       
    // this is the PreviewKeyDown handler for a textbox named tbNumerical
    // Need to add logic for cancelling repeated decimal point and minus sign
    // or possible notation like 1.23e2 == 123
    private void tbNumerical_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Input.Key k = e.Key;

        // to see the key enums displayed, use a textbox or label
        // someTextBox.Text = k.ToString();

        // filter out control keys, not all are used, add more as needed
       bool controlKeyIsDown = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift);      

        if (!controlKeyIsDown &&
            Key.D0 <= k && k <= Key.D9 ||
            Key.NumPad0 <= k && k <= Key.NumPad9 ||
            k == Key.OemMinus || k == Key.Subtract ||
            k == Key.Decimal || k == Key.OemPeriod)   // or OemComma for european decimal point

        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            // just a little sound effect for wrong key pressed
            System.Media.SystemSound ss = System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep;
            ss.Play();

        }
    }
```